# SSRS HTTPS not working for localhost / IP (Bad Request - Invalid Hostname)

Tags: reporting-services, https, bad-request

I have added https binding to my SSRS but somehow it only work with hostname but not localhost and IP, http is working fine for hostname, localhost and IP.

HTTP

https://mypc:123/Reports -> Working

https://192.168.1.22:123/Reports -> NOT Working (Bad Request - Invalid Hostname)

https://localhost:123/Reports -> NOT Working (Bad Request - Invalid Hostname)

HTTP

http://mypc/Reports -> Working

http://192.168.1.22/Reports -> Working

http://localhost/Reports -> Working

Is the any misconfiguration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you configure your https settings correctly in Report Server Configuration Manager. Second, your https port is 443 and not 123. Ex: `https://localhost:443/Reports`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be that the HTTPS configuration was done using a certificate with CN=mypc; if you want to access the Report Server using IP or LocalHost(For some reason) then try creating a certificate with multiple CN values.
But I don't think its a valid use case as IP might change and localhost might not be accessible from clients.